# Insert the entire row using particular cell value using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the problem in this format

```
from hrs  to hrs    quantum  rate
12:00:00  6:00:00   100      1.8
12:00:00  5:00:00   125      1.6
```

I want this data in given format like

```
from hrs    to hrs      quantum  rate
12:00:00    6:00:00     -50      1800.00
12:00:00    6:00:00     -50      1800.00
12:00:00    5:00:00     -50      1600.00
12:00:00    5:00:00     -50      1600.00
12:00:00    5:00:00     -25      1600.00
```

and I am using the below code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim iData As Long, datum As Long, iRow As Long
With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    data = .Resize(, 4).Value
    iData = LBound(data)
    Do
        datum = data(iData, UBound(data, 2) - 1)
        Do While datum > 0
            iRow = iRow + 1
            .Cells(iRow).Resize(, 4) = Application.Index(data, iData, 0)
            .Cells(iRow, UBound(data, 2) - 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Min(50, datum)
            datum = datum - 50
        Loop
        iData = iData + 1
    Loop While iData <= UBound(data)
    .Resize(1).Copy
    .Resize(iRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @user3598756  recoginze this code ?

Comment: @ShaiRado, yes, I do :-)

Comment: You have not asked a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

here it is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim iData As Long, datum As Long, iRow As Long
    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        data = .Resize(, 4).Value
        iData = LBound(data)
        Do
            datum = data(iData, UBound(data, 2) - 1)
            Do While datum > 0
                iRow = iRow + 1
                .Cells(iRow).Resize(, 4) = Application.Index(data, iData, 0)
                .Cells(iRow).Offset(, 3).Value = .Cells(iRow).Offset(, 3).Value * 1000
                .Cells(iRow, UBound(data, 2) - 1).Value = -WorksheetFunction.Min(50, datum)
                datum = datum - 50
            Loop
            iData = iData + 1
        Loop While iData <= UBound(data)
        .Resize(1, 4).Copy
        .Resize(iRow, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @satyendrasharma, after trying this code have a look at [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: sir, when i run the macro it's showing type mismatch error as i am using column heading also pls help

Comment: Not getting you exactly but you may try to change 'Range("A1", Cells(...' to 'Range("A2", Cells(...'. Let me know

Comment: @satyendrasharma, did you get through it?

Comment: @satyendrasharma, would you mind giving feedback? thank you!